# How I can create accounts with command lines for my OpenLDAP server?

Tags: linux, docker, ldap, openldap

I'm in a Docker, in a VM (Ubuntu Serv).
I have created a OpenLDAP server.

I want to know simply : how to create groups and users.

My DIT tree :
dc=company,dc=com
ou=group1 ou=group2 ou=group3 ou=group4
and in each groupe I have many users : cn=user1 cn=user2 etc...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an LDIF for each object like this:

```
dn: uid=cx,ou=group1,ou=People,dc=company,dc=com
loginShell: /bin/bash
objectClass: account
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
objectClass: shadowAccount
userPassword:: ...pwhash.....
cn: Your Name
gecos: The Gecos field (infos),,,
gidNumber: 100
uid: xy
homeDirectory: /home/xy
uidNumber: 1040
```

Then add the thing to the ldap server like this:

```
ldapadd -v -U admin@fs -h 127.0.0.1 -a -f /path/to/ldiffile.ldif
```

You might have to play with the authentication of your initial admin user (Maybe user an DN to auth .... depends on your intial setup)

HTH,
derjohn